# how to use Ice Cream Sandwich UI widgets on Gingerbread?

Tags: android, android-2.3-gingerbread

apologies, since i am a newbie on stackoverflow, i couldn't post pictures properly.

i have implemented [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com) with ["tabs+swipe" navigation](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html#considerations-split-action-bars) on Android 2.3. my aim is to have as-pure-as-possible ICS-experience on Gingerbread. however, native Gingerbread UI widgets still show up, as seen from **THE GREEN STARS** on this picture:

[image]

### so the question is:

- how can i make Gingerbread display a set of native Ice Cream Sandwich UI widgets easily? (i.e., without the fuss of creating everything is a 'custom' manner.)

notes on the picture, so that i don't confuse you:

- the point of interest in the GREEN STARS, which is part of a native Gingerbread UI widget.
- that is my physical Android 2.3.3 tablet.
- it appears with a bottom-of-the-screen-control-bar which closely resembles honeycomb, but that bar is actually just an OEM UI product.

Comment: [HoloEverywhere](http://www.holoeverywhere.com/) is what I am thinking you're looking for **BUT** do not flog the UI as ICS as that is mis-leading!

Comment: @t0mm13b sorry i couldn't understand that. do you mean that i should say "i am looking for a way to implement Holo themes on Gingerbread"?

Comment: No, what I mean is, do not be promoting it as an ICS app... :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the HoloEverywhere project gives you the ability to use Holo-themed widgets on older devices:
https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere

Comment: (well this is a nice quick response for the first question i ever asked...thanks)